# Can one retrieve the content of dvi.tex files?

Tags: dvi

Hello: I still have some dvi.tex files which were created in the times of Textures. They all indicate a size of 0 bytes. Are they really ghosts, or is there a way to retrieve their contents?

Comment: there is no problem getting text from a real dvi file but if the operating system says they have 0 size, there is presumably nothing there and they are not valid dvi. oh dvi.tex? dvi files usually have dvi extension, not tex? (but if they are empty it doesn't really matter what the filename is)

Comment: I'm thinking that Textures might have stored the dvi data into a resource fork. Not sure if that would have survived the transition in whatever media that it came from, but this answer might be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16616/extracting-data-from-old-mac-resource-files

Comment: Thank you for this link! I will see if I can use something there.